# Aplicação Multicliente (multi-tenant) com asp.net webforms e rotas

Tags: asp.net, webforms, multi-tenancy, saas

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Web multi-cliente para um SaaS e gostaria que cada cliente tivesse uma URL diferente para acesso à sua área na aplicação, por exemplo:

http://meudominio.com/cliente1
http://meudominio.com/cliente2

Pensei em criar no IIS uma aplicação para cada cliente, mas isso além de custoso pode degradar a performance do webserver (eu creio).

Existe algum meio de fazer isso usando rotas?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa alterar sua rota:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{cliente}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

E recuperar o valor no controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string cliente)
{
    return View(cliente);
}
```

Comment: Será que isso funciona no webforms? Ja tentei usar esse tipo de rota mas no webforms vc tem que definir qual página a rota serve..ai nao consigo ter uma rota "default" como essa.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/698666/USE-OF-MapPageRoute-Method-IN-ASP-NET-WEBFORM-ROUT